# Indexeddb on Chrome on ios - temporary or persistent? How much is being used?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, indexeddb

here is my situation:
I have to build a mobile web app for Chrome (only) that will work on android, ios, or windows phone. 
The app has to work offline.
The user must be able to take a picture using the camera or select multiple images from the camera roll (potentially >50 at a time).
Its possible 500+ images may be associated with a given entity, but most will be in the 10-30 photo range.
These photos need to be stored on the device and uploaded later on.

indexeddb was used to solve the problem, but we constantly run into "aw snap" errors when the temporary storage is exceeded. On android, I can query the navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage to get usage stats.
But on ios, I get nothing back from the calls and can't find any info on why it doesn't work on ios.

So here are my questions:
Is indexeddb implemented in temporary or persistent storage? I have only been able to find old pages that talk about how it will be changed in the future from one to the other. But no recent updates.
If it is in temporary, can you request more storage space if it fills up? Does this work on android and ios?

And finally... Did I do this the wrong way? 
The indexeddb implementation was handed to me. I'm starting to think it just wont work based on the size and number of images that will be associated with each entity.

How would you solve this kind of problem? (I doubt we will get approval to develop a native app :( )

Comment: Why is this tagged Android if the issue is on iOS?

Comment: Because the web app will need to work on both android and ios

Comment: "indexeddb was used to solve the problem, but we constantly run into "aw snap" errors when the temporary storage is exceeded. " - can you file a bug against Chrome with repro steps? https://crbug.com

Comment: I guess there is a limit to how much files a single site can store on the device temporarily without downloading and storing the data on a permanent location.